# stack overflow - sigsegv error on saved frame pointer

Tags: c, stack, overflow, buffer

I am trying to get a simple buffer overflow working on a 64bit Linux OS. The problem is, it seems that if the saved frame pointer is overwritten I get a bus error (SIGSEGV).

Here is the C code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char *buffer)
{
    char string[24];
    strcpy (string, buffer);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
        func(argv[1]);

    printf("asdf\n");
}
```

I'd love to post screenshots of the memory, but I'm new and I can't…it goes like this:

I overwrite the saved frame pointer with something like 0x4141414141414141 or 0xffffffffffffffff and ret with a valid address like 0x400595.
Then I get a SIGSEGV error...

Here is the input I give to the console:

```
./a.out $(perl -e 'printf "A" x 36 . "\x95\x05\x40";')
```

Comment: Use `strncpy(string, buffer, 23)` then add the null termination.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Strictly, SIGBUS (bus error) is different from SIGSEGV (segmentation violation). Please be precise.

Comment: What makes you think 0x00400595 is a good address to return to?  What are you expecting to happen, and why?  SISGSEGV looks like a reasonable response to me.